# What are the library requirements to writing in VSCode and how can I "sync" my directories through browse.path and settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm literally just trying to write 1 single 'hello world' program in VSCode (in C++), and i've had a ton of obstacles, one being this error:

cd "c:\Users\Zachary\OneDrive\Documents\filename\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\Zachary\OneDrive\Documents\filename\"main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

does win32 mean system32, windows 32 bit, or should I care?? Should I use a different IDE?

Comment: Please post your code. *"Should I use a different IDE?"* It doesn't really matter what IDE you use, only what compiler.

Comment: Is mingw working properly? Can you build the program from the command line? (`g++ main.cpp` to compile from command line).

Comment: This pops up when I try to select the terminal: "The terminal shell CWD "C:\Users\Zachary\OneDrive\Documents\filename" does not exist "

Comment: Also it's a hello world program. I've tested the same code in other compilers and it worked fine